# SQL Relationships - fetching in AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can AMPScript fetch the values from related objects (in the query below, `Account.Name`)?

```
%%[ 
var @rs, @rsRow, @FullName, @AccountName, @Lookup
Set @Lookup = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id, Name,Account.Name', 'Id', '=', @Lookup)

IF RowCount(@rs) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rs) DO
        SET @rsRow = Row(@rs, @i)
        SET @FullName = Field(@rsRow, "Name") // Works
        SET @AccountName = Field(@rsRow, "Account.Name") // Always blank

    NEXT  @i
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Salesforce uses SOQL, but Marketing Cloud uses SQL. They are very different languages.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` function which is querying Salesforce - is that not using SOQL? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm.  I ask as SQL should support aliasing column names, while SOQL doesn't

Comment: Not sure about the mechanics of `RetrieveSalesforceObjects`, I guess it probably would use SOQL. It does support field alias syntax, by the way, it's just that you can only use it in aggregate queries. Probably one of our MC experts will come by and clean things up. That said, you're not really using/constructing your own SOQL here, just AMPScript. Probably should have just removed all commentary on query language.

Comment: Peter, what type of response are you getting?  I don't believe that is possible.  You would need to perform a second retrieve on the Account object.

Comment: @DavidDevoy No error, but nothing output to `%%=v(@AccountName)=%%`. The lack of error makes me think it's fetching back data as the query doesn't fail.